# Issues with canvas scrollbars in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar

**Relevant code:**

```
self.propertyListWrapper = ttk.Frame(self.propertyMenu)
self.propertyListWrapper.pack( fill = tk.BOTH, expand = tk.YES )
self.propertyListCanvas = tk.Canvas(self.propertyListWrapper)
self.propertyListCanvas.pack( fill = tk.BOTH, expand = tk.YES, side = tk.LEFT )
self.propertyGrid = ttk.Frame(self.propertyListCanvas)
self.propertyListScrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.propertyListWrapper)
self.propertyListScrollbar.config(command = self.propertyListCanvas.yview)
self.propertyListCanvas.config(yscrollcommand = self.propertyListScrollbar.set)    
self.propertyListScrollbar.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)

...
# where stuff is added to self.propertyGrid
...

self.propertyListCanvas.config( scrollregion = (0, 0, self.propertyGrid.winfo_width(), self.propertyGrid.winfo_height()))
self.propertyListCanvas.create_window((0,0), window = self.propertyGrid, anchor='nw')
```

This is what is currently happening:
[image: The scrollbar isn't working.]

As you can see, the scrollbar doesn't have a bar. Not very useful.
What am I doing wrong?

Here's a simplified [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/Aarilight/5e374200017ebe9ca023) that duplicates the problem. 20 labels should be there, and you should be able to scroll through them, but the scrollbar doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default for `pack` is to put something along the top edge. When you packed the canvas you're using the default, so it takes up the top of the gui, leaving blank space below. When you packed the scrollbar, you told it to go to the right, so it is at the right edge of the empty space below the canvas. If you want the scrollbar and canvas side-by-side, pack both on the right, or pack one on the right and one on the left.

The problem with your gist is that you're trying to get the width and height of the frame before it has been drawn. Since the frame hasn't been mapped to the screen (because you haven't added it to the canvas yet) it's width and height is 1 (one). You must make a widget visible before you can measure its width and height. That means to add it to a canvas or pack/place/grid it to a visible window and then wait for a screen repaint.

Comment: Make sure you configure the scrollregion after the widgets have had a chance to be drawn on screen -- either after calling `update` or in response to an event.

Comment: @Aarilight: please create a minimal example that duplicates the problem. I can't guess about code I can't see.

Comment: The code that is there should be all that is relevant, but sure. I'm a work right now, I'll make a GitHub gist for it when I get back. ~4 hours

Comment: @Aarilight: if it's too big to fit in the question and requires a gist, it's not useful.  You should be able to replicate the problem with no more than a dozen or two lines of code.

Comment: Added the gist to the question. It's 61 lines. Does that mean I suck at optimising code? xD

Comment: @Aarilight: the problem is that you're trying to get the width and height of the frame. Since the frame hasn't been mapped to the screen (because you haven't added it to the canvas yet) it's width and height is 1 (one). You must make a widget visible before you can measure its width and height. That means to add it to a canvas or pack/place/grid it to a visible window and then wait for a screen repaint.

Comment: Omg, that works. Thank you so much! Could you make that your answer, and then I'll accept it?