# Why is the toolbar working improperly in here(AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, scrollbar

Relevant code:Relevant code:Relevant code:Relevant code:Relevant code:Relevant code:Relevant code:Relevant code:Relevant code:Relevant code:Relevant code:Relevant code:

```
self.propertyListWrapper = ttk.Frame(self.propertyMenu)
self.propertyListWrapper.pack( fill = tk.BOTH, expand = tk.YES )
self.propertyListCanvas = tk.Canvas(self.propertyListWrapper)
self.propertyListCanvas.pack( fill = tk.BOTH, expand = tk.YES, side = tk.LEFT )
self.propertyGrid = ttk.Frame(self.propertyListCanvas)
self.propertyListScrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.propertyListWrapper)
self.propertyListScrollbar.config(command = 
self.propertyListCanvas.yview)
self.propertyListCanvas.config(yscrollcommand = 
self.propertyListScrollbar.set)    
self.propertyListScrollbar.pack(side = tk.RIGHT, fill = tk.Y)


self.propertyListCanvas.config( scrollregion = (0, 0, 
 self.propertyGrid.winfo_width(), self.propertyGrid.winfo_height()))
self.propertyListCanvas.create_window((0,0), window = self.propertyGrid, anchor='nw')
```

Comment: Does the scrollbar become visible? Are there any error codes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues with canvas scrollbars in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27390899/issues-with-canvas-scrollbars-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the canvas to be able to scroll the frame, the frame must be added to the canvas with the `create_window` method.  You can't use `pack`.